# How to use `dd` in order to restore the windows 7 backed up raw files into a new hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, dd

This is the typical case where the windows 7 installation had created a SYSTEM partition of about 1.1GB in size and another partition for the rest of the available space in a hard disk drive.

Currently at our hands we have two files which are raw backups from the dd command: A `system.raw` (~1.1GB) file and a `win7.raw` (~80GB) file.

Edit question extra info: But we also have the initial hdd. However this hdd in total is of size 500GB which is **much larger** than the target drive, which is SSD 90GB. That's why a simple entire drive transfer would not work

How can we restore these seperate partitions to a single hard disk drive using the dd command?
*note: the hard disk drive is empty and has enough available space*

Edit question: We will also need help on how to **align partitions** correctly. Have in mind that the original drive is HDD and the target drive is SSD. From the various tutorials and wikis cannot make sense what is the goal, to align sectors or to align bytes and how to do it exactly in a safe way.

Comment: It would be far easier just to shrink the partition on the old HDD and then DD the entire drive across. That saves at least a half dozen steps and also prevents a lot of mistakes you can make along the way. In fact, if you have DD'd the old partition you must have already shrunk it, at which point literally all you have to do is `dd if=<disk1> of=<disk2> bs=64k`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been better to image the whole disk (or at least, everything up to the end of the partitions you are cloning), since then you wouldn't need to recreate the partitions, but it's still possible.

Basically, you need to re-create the old partition table. First, make sure you have the disk initialized correctly to MBR (sometimes called DOS) mode, or GPT mode, whichever the original disk used. If you aren't sure, and the disk is less than 2TB, go with MBR first.

Use a tool like `gparted` or `qtparted` from a Linux liveCD/live flashdrive to initialize the disk (if needed) and create the partitions, making sure that they are the correct size. Get the sizes as close to perfect as possible - you should be able to make it match exactly - but a little too big is better than a little too small. A too-large partition will merely result in a little wasted space, which isn't that harmful.

If you're using MBR (Master Boot Record), mark the system partition as bootable ("boot flag" or "active"). If you are using GPT (GUID Partition Table), make the system (1.1GB) partition the EFI System Partition. Don't bother to format them or anything, they just need to exist (and have the correct sizes and metadata) in the disk's partition table.

Once the partitions are created, you can copy the data from your backups onto the new drive. The reason you don't need to format is because the backups contain all the file system metadata - the same stuff that would be written out by a formatting tool - so you just need a partition to put the contents of each image file into. The commands will be something like this:

```
dd if=/mount/backup/system.raw of=/dev/sda1 bs=4M
dd if=/mount/backup/win7.raw of=/dev/sda2 bs=4M
```

The `/mount/backup/*.raw` part is the path to the backup images, which are presumably on some external or secondary storage. The `/dev/sda*` parts are the paths to the raw partitions you just created; `sda` means the first hard disk in the system, and the number after it indicates which partition. The partitioning tool should indicate the paths you want, if you aren't sure. The last part just tells `dd` to use a 4MB block size so the copying goes faster; `dd` defaults to a really small block size that makes for very slow copies on modern hardware.

After you have gotten the images expanded back onto the disk, you can use `gparted`'s "fix filesystem" feature to make the file system length match the partition length, though this step shouldn't be necessary (just avoids wasted space). Try booting from the hard disk. It should, hopefully, work. If it doesn't, and you used GPT, you may need to re-do the process, initializing the disk as MBR instead. Additionally/alternatively, you may need to boot off a Win7 install or repair disk, and tell it to do a startup repair process; this should re-install the bootloader and fix the partition metadata.

After you have Win7 booting again, you can use `gparted` to fix the lengths (if you haven't already) and/or use Disk Management in Windows to expand the OS partition into any extra space that you have on the disk.

Comment: We haven't been able to make it work yet but we have not tried everything either. It might help if you could provide the correct flags to set for each paritition using gparted?

Comment: The original drive seems to be formatted using the old/legacy system because we see the boot flag which when we try to set the boot flag in new ssd the gparted also puts the esp flag. This step is also something that is needed for a complete answer.

Comment: For a better answer we will need help on how to align the partitions correctly and not approximately. We have edited the question providing more help

Comment: The alignment should not need to be handled manually, actually! The tool, such as `gparted`, should align the partitions correctly for the drive. All offsets within the partition are relative to the partition, not to the drive, and as long as the partition itself is aligned it should work. The worst that will happen (assuming you hold onto those images and don't overwrite them) is you waste a bit of time.

Comment: perhaps we are using wrong the term "aligning partitions". As far as we know it means that the two partitions, the origin and the target will be compatible to transfer data. Is this correct or ... ?

Comment: Actually the above answer is partially right. Two steps are missing. First of all the drive should be formatted with MBR/DOS and NOT with GPT. Secondly you need to use gparted after the procedure is complete to fix the size of the partitions. After dd the size can be 75GB and you are missing 5GB from the actual partitition. Just right click and select fix filesystem. Thanks for the help but please complete the answer. Also the boot flag must be set in the SYSTEM partition and no flags for the windows partition

Comment: @GeorgePligor: I had no way of knowing whether you were using an MBR or GPT disk originally. I do mention that you have to do some things different depending on the disk format, but I'll make it clearer. Is there some reason you say "*and NOT with GPT*" other than the original disk format? I rescued a GPT disk (using `ddrescue`) recently, though I was able to clone the partition table instead of re-creating it. As for the sizes, if you got the partition size wrong by 5GB... I don't know what to say. But yes, I'll mention the "fix filesystem" feature.

Comment: I had to repeat the process and I must add that a typical startup repair disk for windows 7 is vital to be used on first boot and it is very easy to apply the fix as it is done automatically. Just click on Yes/OK. After reboot you will be asked to have your filesystem checked by windows. Let windows do that as well. Then you are ready to boot